# Tab shortcut for custom JSX components in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, jsx, emmet

I've just made the switch from Atom to VSCode.

When I used Atom and I'm typing JSX in `.js` files, I could type anything and press `tab` and it would turn what I tabbed into a custom component. For example, `asdf` and then `tab` would give `<asdf></asdf>`.

Now I have VSCode along with Emmet but this only works some of the time. I've experimented with Emmet and everything works except for basic custom components

All the HTML tags work as expected. i.e `div.blue` & `tab` return `<div className="blue"></div>`

Nesting works `asdf>jkl` & `tab` return

```
<asdf>
    <jkl></jkl>
</asdf>
```

For some reason adding a colon triggers it. `as:df` & `tab` return `<as:df></as:df>` but `asdf` & `tab` does not return `<asdf></asdf>`. I just get my cursor tabbed forward.

I'm not sure whether Intellisense or Snippets are interfering in some way.
The relevant extensions I have installed are JavaScript and TypeScript Intellisense v0.0.7, Javascript Snippet Pack v0.1.5 and simple React Snippets 1.2.2.

And here are my settings:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "prettier.semi": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Base16 Tomorrow Dark",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0.5,
    "editor.fontSize": 11,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found the answer. In settings add `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` and it will work the way I want it to. By default it was set to `false`